# AWS EMR 4.0 - How can I add a custom JAR step to run shell commands

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am trying to run shell commands using steps on EMR 4.0.0 and used this link for reference - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html

***But I want to know from where to put 'command-runner.jar' in 'JAR location' field*** https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRicz.png

I kept 'command-runner.jar' in AWS s3 and tried to load it from that location and in 'Arguments' gave s3 location of my 'example.sh' file and after adding step it failed giving this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "s3://<path>/example.sh" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
    at com.amazonaws.emr.command.runner.ProcessRunner.exec(ProcessRunner.java:139)
    at com.amazonaws.emr.command.runner.CommandRunner.main(CommandRunner.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "s3://<path>/example.sh" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at com.amazonaws.emr.command.runner.ProcessRunner.exec(ProcessRunner.java:92)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: so you point from the Jar Location ? did you try the CLI from the document you refer in your question ?

Comment: No I didn't. Used AWS console. does it matter?

Comment: no it should not matter, but if console does not work, its good to see if CLI works so if its general error or an error with the use of console

Comment: @Frédéric It didn't work with CLI as well!!!!
Are you sure I am supposed to locate command-runner.jar from s3?

Answer (score 1):

To run a shell script stored in S3, use `script-runner.jar`, which is located at `s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar`.

`command-runner.jar` will work for local files only.

Comment: Thank you Mauricio De Diana,
I have already followed aws documentation to Run a Script in a Cluster [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html) but it did not work out for me.
So I created my own script-runner jar and placed it on S3 and executed my job. Thank you again