# run spark on AWS EMR by passing credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, emr, amazon-emr

I am new to EMR and tried to launch Spark job as a step using something like `command-runner.jar spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class com.xx.xx.className s3n://mybuckets/spark-jobs.jar`
However, the spark job needs credentials as environment variables, my question is what is the best way to pass the credentials as environment variables to the spark jobs. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [AWS EMR 4.0 - How can I add a custom JAR step to run shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151518/aws-emr-4-0-how-can-i-add-a-custom-jar-step-to-run-shell-commands) and here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html
try running step like this(arguments): /usr/bin/spark-submit  --deploy-mode cluster --class

Answer (score 0):

I came to your question googling the solution for myself. Right now as a temp solution, I am passing the credential as cmd line parameters. In the future I am thinking to add a custom bootstrap script which will fetch data from service and create the ~/.aws/credentials and config files. 
I hope this helps or if you have discovered any other option do post here.